# Encoding categorical data with "many" unique values in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, embeddings, one-hot-encoding

I am new to machine learning, in fact, I  am implementing my first deep neural network from scratch without any framework.

The dataset has 3500 rows, and 4 categorial columns of which two have about 160 unique values. The two columns contain the name of Club and Country. The neural network needs to handle such columns, from what I've read many pages, there are some options like

- One hot encoding
- Embedding
- Labeling

I also saw if there are many unique values, One hot encoding will fail. I would like to know what exactly `many` means. Is this a fixed number? or it is just a ratio between the number of training examples and the unique values.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to see as the output of your neural network? Would you share the first five rows of your table?

Comment: To predict wage od players. Link of dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ultimus/football-wages-prediction/versions/1?resource=download

Comment: I see total eight columns in the dataset, which four is the categorial columns, and which two has 160 different values? Is the two are "Club" and "Nation"?

Comment: @CloudCho Yes, Club and Nation.

Comment: So would your input be club, nation, and etc? Is the output from your neural network the player wage? If yes, I don't think that one hot encoding is a good for the club and the country. You would lose geographic information of the input variables. Your output is continuous value, so house price prediction could be similar (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/code?competitionId=5407&sortBy=voteCount)

Comment: @CloudCho then what is your suggestion? It's my first coding in AI.

Comment: I think it depends on your neural network model choice. How about convert "club" to their annual revenue and "nation" to GDP per capita? I think these values affecting more to player salary.